# Easy way to create an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have 2 arrays:

1. first array is a bunch of keys.
2. second array is a bunch of values.

I would like to merge them into an associated array in PHP.

Is there a simpler way to do this other than using loops?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `array_combine()` function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Snippet:

```
$keys = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$values = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$result = array_combine($keys, $values);
var_dump($result);
```

Result:

```
array(4) {
  ["a"]=>
  int(1)
  ["b"]=>
  int(2)
  ["c"]=>
  int(3)
  ["d"]=>
  int(4)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `array_combine`

Example for docs:

```
$a = array('green', 'red', 'yellow');
$b = array('avocado', 'apple', 'banana');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);

print_r($c);
```

Should output:

```
Array
(
    [green]  => avocado
    [red]    => apple
    [yellow] => banana
)
```

Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php